# What is the US equivalent of "Joint of Sirloin"?

Tags: roast-beef

Wanting to make a roast for dinner tonight.  The recipe is a British one calling for 1.5Kg of 'joint of sirloin' but I think the butchers in America call it by 'where' on the sirloin it is.  The recipe calls for roasting it around 55 min.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Any butcher can probably get you a Joint of Sirloin by request, but you will not likely find it "on the shelf".

A "Joint of Sirloin" is a rare cut in the US given the other possible uses of the sirloin.
If one looks at the T-Bone/Porterhouse cuts, where the the "T"-bone bi-sects the steak. The smaller side is the tenderloin and the larger side is sirloin. While it is not entirely uncommon for the short-loin primal to be cut to form a tenderloin roast from that side of the "joint" when that is done the sirloin is then usually (in the US) trimmed to be either "New York Strips" or "Kansas City Strips".

[image: Here we see a section of the short loin primal, from this end only a thin layer of fat separate the tender loin from the sirloin.]

Here we see a section of the short loin primal, from this end only a thin layer of fat separate the tender loin from the sirloin.

[image]

And this is the trimmed joint of sirloin.

[image]

And the Bone-in version of the joint of sirloin

Comment: Usually, in my area at least (north, UK), we call use the name sirloin for the steak and striploin for the whole joint.

Comment: Indeed, I have learned that cuts which we may think of as 'common' are often far more localized than we know.